# How to change android RecyclerView child view height programatically?

Tags: android, data-binding, android-recyclerview

I want to change my `RecyclerView` items height programatically to `match_parent` or `wrap_content` due to size of content. How to change the height of child item?

```
DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(binding.RVOperation.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
binding.RVOperation.setLayoutManager(staggeredGridLayoutManager);
binding.RVOperation.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
Log.d("COUNTT", String.valueOf(binding.RVOperation.getAdapter().getItemCount()));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override onBindViewHolder in your RecyclerView and call setLayoutParams on the viewholder's container.

example:

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(SimpleItemViewHolder holder, int position){
 // do whatever here

 // add your layout parameters here. Here I'm setting the width and height to match parent
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); //(width,height)
    holder.container.setLayoutParams(params);
 }
```

[Source](https://viksaaskool.wordpress.com/2015/05/08/adjust-recyclerview-item-height-example/)